# Как отобразить структуру данных в виде таблицы?

Tags: html, vue.js

Получилось вывести на экран почти всю таблицу, но случается загвоздка с выводом раздела Итого Клиент 1, итого клиент 2
Который должен находить под полем Клиент
Структура данных следующая[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
objects: [{
  data: [
    {
      road: "Дорога_1",
      attr1: [
        {
          attr2: "Клиент_1",
          attr3: [
            { road: "Дорога_2", cargo: "нефть1", amount: "1", wo_nds: "1" },
            { road: "Дорога_3", cargo: "нефть2", amount: "12", wo_nds: "12"},
            { road: "Дорога_4",cargo: "нефть3",amount: "3",wo_nds: "31" },
          ],
          attr4: {cargo: "СУММА", amount: "СУММА", wo_nds: "СУММА"}
        },
        {
          attr2: "Клиент_2",
          attr3: [
            { road: "Дорога_5", cargo: "рис1", amount: "14", wo_nds: "41" },
            { road: "Дорога_6", cargo: "рис2", amount: "15", wo_nds: "61" },
          ],
          attr4: {cargo: "СУММА", amount: "СУММА", wo_nds: "СУММА"}
        },
      ],
      TOTAL : {
        cargo: 'TOTAL',
        amount: 'TOTALA',
        wo_nds: 'TOTALWO'
      }
    },
  ],
  ALL_TOTAL: {
    cargo: 'ALL_TOTAL',
    amount: 'ALL_TOTALA',
    wo_nds: 'ALL_TOTALWO'
  }
}],
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.13/vue.js"></script>
      <template v-for="obj in this.objects[0].data">
        <tr :key="obj.id">
          <td :rowspan="getRowCount(obj)">{{ obj.road }}</td>
          <td :rowspan="obj.attr1[0].attr3.length">{{ obj.attr1[0].attr2 }}</td>
          <td>{{ obj.attr1[0].attr3[0].road }}</td>
          <td>{{ obj.attr1[0].attr3[0].cargo }}</td>
          <td>{{ obj.attr1[0].attr3[0].amount }}</td>
          <td>{{ obj.attr1[0].attr3[0].wo_nds }}</td>
        </tr>

        <tr v-for="val2 in obj.attr1[0].attr3.slice(1)" :key="val2.id">
          <td>{{ val2.road }}</td>
          <td>{{ val2.cargo }}</td>
          <td>{{ val2.amount }}</td>
          <td>{{ val2.wo_nds }}</td>
        </tr>


        
        <template v-for="subkey in obj.attr1.slice(1)">
          <tr :key="subkey.id">
            <td :rowspan="subkey.attr3.length" class="road2">{{ subkey.attr2 }}</td>
            <td>{{ subkey.attr3[0].road }}</td>
            <td>{{ subkey.attr3[0].cargo }}</td>
            <td >{{ subkey.attr3[0].amount }}</td>
            <td >{{ subkey.attr3[0].wo_nds }}</td>
          </tr>

          <tr v-for="value3 in subkey.attr3.slice(1)" :key="value3.id">
            <td class="road2">{{ value3.road }}</td>
            <td class="road2">{{ value3.cargo }}</td>
            <td class="road2">{{ value3.amount }}</td>
            <td class="road2">{{ value3.wo_nds }}</td>
          </tr>
        </template>

        <tr class="total_row" :key="obj.id">
            <td>Итого {{ obj.road }}</td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td>{{ obj.TOTAL.cargo }}</td>
            <td>{{ obj.TOTAL.amount }}</td>
            <td >{{ obj.TOTAL.wo_nds }}</td>

        </tr>
      </template>
      <tr v-for="obj in objects" :key="obj.id">
        <td style="font-weight: bold;">Всего погрузки</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>{{ obj.ALL_TOTAL.cargo }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.ALL_TOTAL.amount }}</td>
        <td>{{ obj.ALL_TOTAL.wo_nds }}</td>

      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</template>
```